# setInterval not working as expected with counting function

Tags: javascript

I know this may be an easy answer, but I am having trouble using my function with `setInterval`.  Here is what I have so far:

```
function countUp(n) {
     console.log(n++);
}

setInterval( function() { countUp(10); }, 1000);
```

If I move my variable outside the function and increment that value, it will work.  However, I want to be able to set the number to anything when I call the function `countUp`.  The above code just keeps logging `10`.

**EDIT:**

Is there any way to pass an argument to this function and make it work with setInterval without having to declare a global variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to increment a variable in the enclosing scope of the function:

```
var n = 10;

function countUp() {
    console.log(n++);
}

setInterval(countUp, 1000);
```

**Update:** Here's a strategy that doesn't involve a global variable:

```
function countUp(start) {
    return function() {
        console.log(start++)
    }
}
setInterval(countUp(10), 1000);
```

As I noted, the counter just needs to be in the enclosing scope, not the global scope. So passing it into a function that can reference it in a closure will work fine here.

Comment: Right, I understand that. I actually outlined it in the original question. Is there anyway to pass it as argument without declaring a global variable?

Comment: This does work.  Exactly what I was looking for.  Why do we have to return another function though??

Comment: The inner function is what actually gets called by `setInterval` - the outer function just creates the inner function, allowing it to reference a persistent counter variable in the closure.

Comment: That clears it up.  The returned function is a closure with it's own private scope that has access to the argument being passed.  Makes sense.